# Menu icon doesn't show up in Safari on desktop or at all on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

This is the mobile menu I have created for window sizes of 735px or less. The mobile menu icon (top right corner) doesn't show up in Safari on desktop or any mobile browsers (including Chrome and Safari). I have a feeling I might be overlooking something obvious, but I just can't figure it out.

Could it be something to do with overflow:hidden? I found that if I disable it in my class .mobilenav, the menu icon shows up, but obviously, the close icon does as well. If this is the root of the problem, how can I fix it while keeping the menu's functionality intact?

Browsers it works in on desktop: Chrome 75.0.3770.142, Firefox 68.0, Edge 42.17134.1.0 Browsers it doesn't work in on desktop: Safari 12.1.1 On mobile, it doesn't seem to work in any browser. I checked both Safari and Chrome.

```js
// BEGIN MOBILE NAV
function openMobile() {
  document.getElementById("myMobilenav").style.width = "100%";
  document.getElementById("myMobilenav").style.borderLeft = "none";
}

function closeMobile() {
  document.getElementById("myMobilenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("myMobilenav").style.borderLeft = "none";
}
// END MOBILE NAV

//  MOBILE DROPDOWN
//* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content\*/
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("mobileactive");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

document.getElementById("myMobilenav").ontouchmove = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width:735px) {
  .nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .navcontainer {
    display: none;
  }
  header.Header.Header--top {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* END MAIN NAV STYLE */

.mobilehead {
  width: 120px !important;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-top: -10px;
}

#mobilehead {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #e9e5fb;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}


/* BEGIN MOBILE NAV STYLE */

.mobilenavcontainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: #e9e5fb;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 997;
}

#mobilemenuicon {
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 5000;
}

.mobilenav .mobilemenuicon {
  top: 20px;
  right: 18px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 50000;
}

#mobilecloseicon {
  width: 80px;
}

.mobilenav .mobileclosebtn {
  top: 20px;
  right: 18px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.mobilenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #e9e5fb;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 120px;
  font-family: "AmerigoBT";
}

.mobilemainitems a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  -webkit-text-stroke: .75px #000;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #e9e5fb;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
}

.mobilemainitems {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: -96px;
}

.mobilesocialitems a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.mobilesocialitems {
  padding-left: 30px;
  line-height: 35px;
  top: 480px;
  position: absolute;
}

.row1social {
  padding-left: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 250px !important;
}


/* dropdown button */

.mobile-dropdown-btn {
  font-family: "AmerigoBT";
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  line-height: 54px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: -11px !important;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}


/* active class for active dropdown button */

.mobileactive a {
  background-color: none;
  -webkit-text-stroke: .75px #000 !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #e9e5fb !important;
}


/* dropdown container */

.mobile-dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-family: "UniversEx";
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.mobile-dropdown-container a {
  line-height: 32px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #000 !important;
  -webkit-text-stroke: transparent !important;
}

.mobile-dropdown-container a:hover {
  color: #000 !important;
  -webkit-text-stroke: transparent !important;
}

@media (min-width:736px) {
  .mobilenav {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobilenavcontainer {
    display: none;
  }
  #mobilehead {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="mobilehead"><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c8e8d07a09a7e3c68de4c7b/t/5d07d5346b960f00012d395a/1560794420116/ck4%40300x.png" alt="Cathrine Khom" class="mobilehead" /></header>

<!-- BEGIN MOBILE NAV -->
<div id="myMobilenav" class="mobilenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mobileclosebtn" onclick="closeMobile()"><img id="mobilecloseicon" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c8e8d07a09a7e3c68de4c7b/t/5d07e8d86b960f00012f1522/1560799448192/closeup%40300x.png" /></a>
  <div class="mobilemainitems">
    <button class="mobile-dropdown-btn"><a href="#">Journal</a></button>
    <div class="mobile-dropdown-container">
      <a href="/journal">all</a>
      <a href="/journal?category=design">design</a>
      <a href="/journal?category=fashion">fashion</a>
      <a href="/journal?category=personal">personal</a>
      <a href="/journal?category=swoon">swoon</a>
      <a href="/journal?category=travel">travel</a>
    </div>
    <a href="/work">Work</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="mobilesocialitems">
    <div class="row1social">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Twitter</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Instagram</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row2social">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Pinterest</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Magazine</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Spotify</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mobilenavcontainer">
  <span class="mobilenav" onclick="openMobile()"><img id="mobilemenuicon" class="mobilemenuicon" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c8e8d07a09a7e3c68de4c7b/t/5d07d2bda44aaa000188164d/1560793789313/menudown%40300x.png"/></span>
</div>
<!-- END MOBILE NAV -->
```

Comment: `@media (max-width:735px) {
  .nav {
    display: none;
  }` makes it disappear on large devices. You may want to include `<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale:1, user-scalable=no' />`, in your head, or something similar, so the scale is correct, as well.

Comment: Thank you. I have something similar to what you suggested in the head of my code for the full menu, I just didn't happen to include it here. This menu doesn't appear at sizes larger than 735px, as it is only for mobile, so that's not the problem. The problem is that the menu icon doesn't show up in Safari at sizes below 736px (like it should) if you view it in a desktop browser at or below that size. If you try to view it in Safari or Chrome on an iPhone it also doesn't show up. The menu is there and functioning, as it should be. But the icon that opens the menu is absent.

Comment: Maybe that meta tag won't do the job, but it could be that your screen is larger than you think. http://javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cssmediaqueries2.shtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're nesting fixed positioned elements but for whatever reason Safari is getting lost with it's layers because of it.

Adding the following solves your problem on Safari and mobile...

```
.mobilenavcontainer > .mobilenav {
  position: relative;
}
```

```js
// BEGIN MOBILE NAV
function openMobile() {
  document.getElementById("myMobilenav").style.width = "100%";
  document.getElementById("myMobilenav").style.borderLeft = "none";
}

function closeMobile() {
  document.getElementById("myMobilenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("myMobilenav").style.borderLeft = "none";
}
// END MOBILE NAV

//  MOBILE DROPDOWN
//* Loop through all dropdown buttons to toggle between hiding and showing its dropdown content\*/
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-dropdown-btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("mobileactive");
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}

document.getElementById("myMobilenav").ontouchmove = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width:735px) {
  .nav {
    display: none;
  }
  .navcontainer {
    display: none;
  }
  header.Header.Header--top {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* END MAIN NAV STYLE */

.mobilehead {
  width: 120px !important;
  display: block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-top: -10px;
}

#mobilehead {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #e9e5fb;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #000;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
}


/* BEGIN MOBILE NAV STYLE */

.mobilenavcontainer {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: #e9e5fb;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 997;
}

.mobilenavcontainer > .mobilenav {
  position: relative;
}

#mobilemenuicon {
  width: 80px;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 5000;
}

.mobilenav .mobilemenuicon {
  top: 20px;
  right: 18px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 50000;
}

#mobilecloseicon {
  width: 80px;
}

.mobilenav .mobileclosebtn {
  top: 20px;
  right: 18px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.mobilenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #e9e5fb;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 120px;
  font-family: "AmerigoBT";
}

.mobilemainitems a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 3em;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  -webkit-text-stroke: .75px #000;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #e9e5fb;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
}

.mobilemainitems {
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: -96px;
}

.mobilesocialitems a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.mobilesocialitems {
  padding-left: 30px;
  line-height: 35px;
  top: 480px;
  position: absolute;
}

.row1social {
  padding-left: 50px;
  display: block;
  width: 250px !important;
}


/* dropdown button */

.mobile-dropdown-btn {
  font-family: "AmerigoBT";
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  color: #000;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
  line-height: 54px;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 200px;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  margin-left: -11px !important;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}


/* active class for active dropdown button */

.mobileactive a {
  background-color: none;
  -webkit-text-stroke: .75px #000 !important;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #e9e5fb !important;
}


/* dropdown container */

.mobile-dropdown-container {
  display: none;
  background-color: none;
  padding-left: 20px;
  font-family: "UniversEx";
  font-size: 11px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.mobile-dropdown-container a {
  line-height: 32px;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #000 !important;
  -webkit-text-stroke: transparent !important;
}

.mobile-dropdown-container a:hover {
  color: #000 !important;
  -webkit-text-stroke: transparent !important;
}

@media (min-width:736px) {
  .mobilenav {
    display: none;
  }
  .mobilenavcontainer {
    display: none;
  }
  #mobilehead {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="mobilehead"><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c8e8d07a09a7e3c68de4c7b/t/5d07d5346b960f00012d395a/1560794420116/ck4%40300x.png" alt="Cathrine Khom" class="mobilehead" /></header>

<!-- BEGIN MOBILE NAV -->
<div id="myMobilenav" class="mobilenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="mobileclosebtn" onclick="closeMobile()"><img id="mobilecloseicon" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c8e8d07a09a7e3c68de4c7b/t/5d07e8d86b960f00012f1522/1560799448192/closeup%40300x.png" /></a>
  <div class="mobilemainitems">
    <button class="mobile-dropdown-btn"><a href="#">Journal</a></button>
    <div class="mobile-dropdown-container">
      <a href="/journal">all</a>
      <a href="/journal?category=design">design</a>
      <a href="/journal?category=fashion">fashion</a>
      <a href="/journal?category=personal">personal</a>
      <a href="/journal?category=swoon">swoon</a>
      <a href="/journal?category=travel">travel</a>
    </div>
    <a href="/work">Work</a>
    <a href="/about">About</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="mobilesocialitems">
    <div class="row1social">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Twitter</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Instagram</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row2social">
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Pinterest</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Magazine</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <a href="#" target="_blank">Spotify</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="mobilenavcontainer">
  <span class="mobilenav" onclick="openMobile()"><img id="mobilemenuicon" class="mobilemenuicon" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/5c8e8d07a09a7e3c68de4c7b/t/5d07d2bda44aaa000188164d/1560793789313/menudown%40300x.png"/></span>
</div>
<!-- END MOBILE NAV -->
```

Comment: That's amazing. Thank you so much for your help!