# Mobile menu Icon doesn't show up in Safari or on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've asked this question here so many times and no one could figure out the issue. I've created a mobile menu for sizes of 735px or less and the icon that is used to open it, doesn't show up in Safari or any browser on iPhone. Code and question details can be found here: [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57155753/11623961).

I tried using the same image in a similar menu I created for a different site and it showed up without any issues in Safari. I've spent weeks on this without any clue as to why it wasn't working. I've checked the console for warnings and none appeared.

The image shows up anywhere else on the page if I place it outside of the menu.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that those two console errors are unrelated to your image issue that you are experiencing. Can you try undo any media queries you have done (comment them out) and see if you can get the image to display fine on the device you were testing on?

Comment: Thanks. I undid the queries and it still didn't show up. However, if I just put the image on the page within an img tag, outside of the menu, it shows up fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a working link or codepen equivelant you can share? It's a bit harder to troubleshoot if the entire implementation isn't visible. How are you trying to display the image? If it displays, after you've disabled all CSS rules, then it is a CSS declaration that is causing the issue.

Comment: I've posted [an answer to your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57155753/menu-icon-doesnt-show-up-in-safari-on-desktop-or-at-all-on-mobile/57228356#57228356).